# Does Japan have a nuclear phase out plan similar to that of Germany?

Tags: japan, nuclear-energy

In 2011 [Fukushima Daiichi reactor suffered a meltdown](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2018/mar/16/is-fukushima-doomed-to-become-a-dumping-ground-for-toxic-waste) with tremendous consequences. The same source argues about Japan's issues related to storing nuclear waste:

> Japan possesses approximately 17,000 tonnes of spent fuel from nuclear
>   power operations (..) Most spent fuel rods are still stored
>   precariously above ground, in pools, in a highly earthquake-prone
>   nation.

[This article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/can-japan-do-without-nuclear-energy/) argues about pressures put on Japan to reduce dependency on nuclear power following Fukushima meltdown:

> Most experts agree that Japan would be hard pressed to close all of
>   its 54 nuclear reactors anytime soon

**Question:** Does Japan have a nuclear phase out plan similar to [the German one](https://www.dw.com/en/germanys-nuclear-phase-out-explained/a-39171204)?

> Germany has measures on the books to close all of the country's
>   nuclear reactors by 2022.

Comment: The "tremendous consequence" of the Fukushima accidents are nothing compared to the consequence of global warming caused, among other things, by coal and oil power plants.

Comment: Are Germany and Japan geographically similar enough that the ability to access alternatives to nuclear fission are comparable?  If Germany wants to build wind farms on open land, and Japan, being a relatively mountainous island nation, doesn't have that option, is it a good model for comparison? Note - I ask this without any knowledge of what Germany's actual plan is.

Comment: To be noted that the most tremendous consequences so far have been the most of the relocation which cost lives and capital. Radiation casualties none so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plan is to reduce nuclear power but there is no total phase-out plan with a fixed deadline at present

Japan originally had a plan to "enable nuclear power generation to be at zero during the 2030s" as stated by [dw.com](https://www.dw.com/en/japan-plans-nuclear-phase-out-by-2040/a-16240522):

> "The government will introduce every possible policy resource that would enable nuclear power generation to be at zero during the 2030s," a government paper released on Friday said.

5 days later [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2012/sep/19/japan-2040-nuclear-power-exit) announced the government's plan to remove nuclear power had been dropped:

> Japan has effectively abandoned a commitment to end its reliance on nuclear power by 2040 amid pressure from the country's business lobby, dropping a deadline recommended by a cabinet panel only days ago.

However, [The Conversation](http://theconversation.com/six-years-after-fukushima-much-of-japan-has-lost-faith-in-nuclear-power-73042) has cited 2 reports which state that a rather significant (47.9-73%) portion of people surveyed support a gradual phaseout of nuclear power:

> [In a 2015 poll by the pro-nuclear Japan Atomic Energy Relations Organization](http://www.jaero.or.jp/data/01jigyou/pdf/tyousakenkyu27/r2015.pdf), 47.9 percent of respondents said that nuclear energy should be abolished gradually and 14.8 percent said that it should be abolished immediately. Only 10.1 percent said that the use of nuclear energy should be maintained, and a mere 1.7 percent said that it should be increased.
>
> [Another survey by the newspaper Asahi Shimbun in 2016](http://www.asahi.com/ajw/articles/AJ201610180076.html) was even more negative. Fifty-seven percent of the public opposed restarting existing nuclear power plants even if they satisfied new regulatory standards, and 73 percent supported a phaseout of nuclear power, with 14 percent advocating an immediate shutdown of all nuclear plants.

Comment: So, there is no clear plan for phasing out nuclear power generation, right?

Comment: The plan is reduce nuclear power but there is no total phase out plan with fixed deadline at present

Comment: Not admitting any new plants is an economic way to slowly phase out. Each power plant after all has a life span.